# Running python in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Currently I have python 3.10 and I am trying to run a simple program in VS Code. I get the error message 'Program 'python3.10.exe' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specified'. I checked my environmental variables and they look correct along with my pip installation. It is asking for a path that is not present. I previously python and vscode then took it off and reinstalled. How do I change where VS Code looks for my python.exe?

Comment: Try explicitly selecting the correct environment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Answer (score 1):

You can select your python version in Visual Studio Code. I use 3 versions of python that 3.10, 3.9.8, 3.9.7.

Anyway bottom of your vscode, and you can see the python version. Click it on it will be show like [this.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)
And change that python version you reinstalled.

Additionally I'm recommend using virtual develop environments like anaconda or virtualenv stuff. When if you messed up or got a issue with module or python version errors ... remove or rebuild develop environment in your pc. I hope you solved with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyboard shortcut "ctrl+shift+P" and type "python:select interpreter"

Then choose the correct one.
[image]

You could refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more details.